# How to delete azure resource automatically after a period of time

Tags: azure, azure-automation

How can we delete an azure resource automatically after a period of time? I want to delete the resources based on the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not natively supported** by Azure but could be easily done using a **time-triggered Azure Function** that has, for example, *Contributor* rights to your subscription and iterates over your Azure resources. It then retrieves their tags and deletes the resources if certain conditions are met.

If you want to implement it yourself, these are the resources you are looking for:

- [Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer)
- [How to use managed identities for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)
- [What is role-based access control (RBAC) for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview)
- PowerShell cmdlets:[Get-AzResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-3.0.0) and [Remove-AzResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.Resources/Remove-AzResource?view=azps-3.0.0)